# Is the phrasal verb ( Set about) commonly used by natives?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is the phrasal verb “Set about”, meaning: (To start doing something) something that native speakers commonly use?

Examples/

1) She had no idea how to set about her work.

2) We got up early and set about cleaning our house.

Comment: I wouldn't say its *common*, but it's certainly used. It has a kind of formal air to it, so it would be something I'd expect in literature.

Comment: Its used. Id say its not too uncommon